# Set drop down list selected value to value in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

What I'm trying to do is set a drop down list to be whatever its value is in the database when editing an entry. I am able to save the value of the drop down list to the database just fine, but I can't seem to set the control in the browser to show this. I.E. The selected value of "4" is saved to the database for entry ABC, but when I return to this entry to edit it again, this is not the selected value--it's the first item in the drop down list.

This is the code I have that is meant to set the selected value of the drop down upon editing an entry, but it does not work:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
{
     cn.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, cn);
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", custIDHidden.Value));

      using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          if (reader.Read())
          { 
              TaxExemptDDL.SelectedValue = reader["TaxExemptFile"].ToString();


           }
       }
        cn.Close();
}
```

The control itself (the value is what gets stored in the database, not the text):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="TaxExemptDDL" style="width:165px;" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="1" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? It seems like it would be simple to do but I appear to have it wrong somehow...

Comment: Please explain your code more details ... what's  "reader"?could you place the entire code?

Comment: assuming the reader returns a 1 or 0 it should work, then the question is when are you doing this.  if the control is bound after you set the value it will be reset to the default.

Comment: Where is your population of dropdownlist items?you should change SelectedValue just after DataBind()

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the SelectedValue like that.

```
ListItem itemToSelect = TaxExemptDDL.Items.FindByValue(reader["TaxExemptFile"].ToString());
if (itemToSelect != null)
{
TaxExemptDDL.SelectedIndex = TaxExemptDDL.Items.IndexOf(itemToSelect);
}
```

Why doesn't someone make it easier to post code here? Like other sites where you can put stuff between [Code] tags and it formats the code. It is hard work posting code here. And edits don't always update either.

Comment: What happens when you debug it? Is itemToSelect null? If it is, the value of reader["TaxExemptFile"] does not exist as the value of an item in the dropdownlist. I am not familiar with your reader syntax. I would say if (reader.HasRows) { while (reader.Read()) etc.

Comment: It appears to be that itemToSelect is null, which is odd because in the database, the value for TaxExemptFile is 0.

Answer (score 0):

**u can add items to the dropdownlist by manually from design or from values from database.
if u are in a page for editing and u want to set the dropdownlist selected value as in the database value, then take the selected value from database to string and do like this.
in my example i want to show the course list in dropdownlist & my selected course in database is "php".
Bt my dropdownlist is in the order of

android

asp.net

java

php

in PageLoad**

string course="php";

ListItem itm = new ListItem("course", "course");

DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(itm);

now when page loads dropdownlist selected item will be "php".